# javascript negative number in pull down

Tags: php, javascript

When I click "EDIT" link on a specific user it is suppose to tell me how many vacation days he/she has left... the Edit link is like this:

```
print "<a href=\"javascript:editUser('$data[uid]','$data[vacationdays]')\">Edit</a>\n";
```

So when i click EDIT on ADMIN account:
javascript:editUser('Admin','-3.0') is the actual values

The javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function editUser(uid, vacationdays) {
    document.userForm.uid.value = uid;
    document.userForm.vacationdays.value = vacationdays;
    document.location.href = "#AddEdit";
    }
</script>
```

The website PHP/HTML:

```
Vacation days: <select name="vacationdays" id="vacationdays" />
               <?php 
               for ($i=-30.5;$i<30.5;$i+=0.5)
               echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
               ?>
               </select>
```

The problem is only with negative numbers (-1 or -2...etc) not showing up in the form pull down menu. Positive numbers show up no problem.

Example positive number:
[image]

Example negative number: [image]

**** i dont want to be able to select a negative values from the pull down.. but if the value is negative i just want it to show once and when you click on the pull down you can only select positive numbers ****

If i change the pulldown to a TEXTFIELD it works perfectly fine with negative numbers...weird?

Comment: Your code doesn't create negative numbers... Your `for` loop starts at 0.  So of course no negative numbers.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem? Just begin the start of your list with let's say `-30.5`: `for ($i=-30.5;$i<30.5;$i+=0.5)`...

Comment: where are negative numbers? i>0 to i<30.5.

Comment: i dont want to be able to select a negative values from the pull down.. but if the value is negative i just want it to show once and when you click on the pull down you can only select positive numbers

Comment: you could remove the negative option once a positive one has been selected (or when something else happens. UI-wise, I don't reccomend that, though

Comment: even if i use $i=-30.5;$i<30.5;$i+=0.5   this does not work either.  the default value of vacationdays is being fetched from SQL DB

Comment: if i change the pull down to a textfield then negative numbers show up... but not for pull down ... weird!??!?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the negative numbers to your list :

```
function vacationdays_list() {
    for ($i=-30.5; $i<30.5; $i+=0.5)
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: i dont want to be able to select a negative values from the pull down.. but if the value is negative i just want it to show once and when you click on the pull down you can only select positive numbers

Comment: @rubberchicken in this case, avoid selecting negative values with some javascript code since in order to display some values in a dropdown list is to have this value in the list...

Comment: even if i use $i=-30.5;$i<30.5;$i+=0.5 this does not work either. the default value of vacationdays is being fetched from SQL DB -- if i change the pull down to a textfield then negative numbers show up... but not for pull down

Answer (score 0):

generate list for negative number between -30.5 till 0

```
 for ($i=-30.5;$i<0;$i+=0.5)
    echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
```

generate list for number between -30.5 till +30.5

```
 for ($i=-30.5;$i<30.5;$i+=0.5)
    echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
```

if you want always selected be a positive number you can use Absolute `abs()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php in php  or `Math.abs` in JavaScript

generate list for number between -30.5 till +30.5 that negative number is disabled

```
for ($i=0;$i<30.5;$i+=0.5)
    echo "<option value=\"$i\" >$i</option>\n";  
for ($i=-30.5;$i<0;$i+=0.5)
    echo "<option value=\"$i\" disabled>$i</option>\n";
```

edit:

```
 Vacation days: <select name="vacationdays" id="vacationdays" />
           <?php 
           for ($i=30.5;$i>0;$i-=0.5)
              echo "<option value=\"$i\" >$i</option>\n";  
           for ($i=0;$i>-30.5;$i-=0.5)
              echo "<option value=\"$i\" disabled>$i</option>\n";  
           ?>
           </select>
```

Comment: or `echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>\n';` :)

Comment: can u take alook at my edit above -- even with -30.5 in my for loop it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `echo` your function, so it should be

```
Vacation days: <select name="vacationdays" id="vacationdays" />
               <?php vacationdays_list(); ?>
               </select>
```

and for negative numbers

```
function vacationdays_list() {
    for ($i=-30.5; $i<30.5; $i+=0.5)
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
}
```